# Debugging python 3.7 in LLDB on MacOS 10.15.6

Tags: python, macos, lldb

I'm running a Mac with Catalina 10.15.6 on an Intel MBP.  I'm trying to debug a C++ library that has a Python 3.7.7 binding, Python being installed in a venv. I used to be able to debug it via lldb by going,

`` lldb `which python` -- -m pytest myCrashingTest.py ``

Then calling 'run', have it segfault and then do the normal debug fandango.

Now when I call 'run' it tells me...

> error: process exited with status -1 (Error 1)

If I try to debug python on it's own, that gives me the same error.

`` lldb `which python` ``

I can't figure this one and can't find any thing useful via google searches. If I try to debug system python, I gets a System Integrity Error, which I can get round if need be, but I'm not running system python. I'm being forced to put in debug prints in the C++ lib like it's the 1980s all over again.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When SIP is on, lldb is not allowed to debug system binaries, and more generally any binaries that are codesigned and not marked as willing to be debugged.  The system Python does not opt into being debugged, so you will either have to turn off SIP (not sure how you do that in a venv) or build a debug version of python yourself.  I generally do the latter, Python isn't that hard to build.